# squareup button on adobe form

Tags: java, forms, adobe, square-connect

I want to make an ADOBE ACROBAT form for people to apply for a summer music school.  The form will be on our WEB site.  Applicants must pay when they apply.  There is no 'apply now and pay later' allowed.  I want to put a button on the form that will:

```
 1. Take them to our Squareup account so they can pay by credit card.
 2. Come back to the form with information that the card is OK or not.
```

I have looked at the Squareup API instructions and they are way past my ability to understand.  I am hoping to have something similar to the button provided by Jot Form.  Before you ask, my organization does not want to use Jot Form -- I don't know why and I am done asking.

All I need is to get a button working in Adobe.  After that, I can take it from there.

Comment: In my opinion there's a lot of things to do and setup to get this working. I'm not sure that a simple button will help you enough. I would suggest to look at online tutorials, even if they aren't language related but just to get the idea of the whole payment process. I'm not sure Stack is the best place for this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for isn't likely possible. You could link out to a different online store but bringing the info back to the form would not be possible.